# Batch file issues

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file that removes all attributes to .jpg files and then deletes the jpg(s) in that directory.  Great for ripped music.  I have many directories in my `MY MUSIC` folder.  I'd like to put my `DelHiddenJpg.bat` in `MY MUSIC` directory and run it and have it preform those commands in all the subdirectories. This is what is in the `DelHiddenJpg.bat`

```
attrib -S -H *.jpg
Del *.jpg
```

Is there anyway to do this without having to drop `DelHiddenJpg.bat` in every subdirectory?

Answer (score 4):

`attrib /S` does subdirectories recursively.

`del /S` also also does subdirectories recursively.

So if you want to sit in the "My Music" directory and do a recursive delete you can do

```
attrib /S -S -H *.jpg
del /S *.jpg
```

There is also `del /F` - force delete - which may allow you to delete without changing the attribs first.

Also check `del /Q` - Quiet mode - this suppresses the Delete (Y/N) question.

By the way, `attrib -S` (different from `attrib /S`), removes the System attrib - not sure why your jpgs will have the system attribute set.

On the other hand, if I have misunderstood your question and you don't want to do a recursive delete, but want to just do one directory at a time, but do not want to have a copy of the batch file in each subdirectory, then this is what you can do.

- your batch file should have your original commands (without the `/S`)
- keep the batch file in any particular directory (for eg . in `c:\bin` or `c\batch`) and add this directory to your path - you can do this from Control Panel->System if you want it to be  automatically set for any new command window which is opened.
- Whichever directory you want to run it in, just cd to that directory and run `DelHiddenJpg` - it will be picked up from the path.